# Sorting a table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to sort the below table XYZ using sql,
here Id is the primary key.

```
----------------------------------------
Id | Date        |Product   | Time 
----------------------------------------
1  | 01-02-2016  |C         |10:00
2  | 01-02-2016  |B         |10:30
3  | 01-02-2016  |A         |11:00
4  | 01-02-2016  |C         |11:30
5  | 01-02-2016  |B         |12:00
6  | 01-02-2016  |A         |12:30
7  | 01-02-2016  |C         |13:00
8  | 01-02-2016  |B         |13:30
9  | 02-02-2016  |D         |07:00
10 | 02-02-2016  |C         |07:30
11 | 02-02-2016  |E         |08:00
12 | 02-02-2016  |D         |08:30
13 | 02-02-2016  |E         |09:00
14 | 02-02-2016  |A         |09:30
```

I need to sort it in such a way to find the Product with the minimum time for each day and sort by time, then the Product with the next earliest time and sort by time in the following manner.

```
Id  |Date      |Product |Time 
1   |01-02-2016|    C   |10:00
4   |01-02-2016|    C   |11:30
7   |01-02-2016|    C   |13:00
2   |01-02-2016|    B   |10:30
5   |01-02-2016|    B   |12:00
8   |01-02-2016|    B   |13:30
3   |01-02-2016|    A   |11:00
6   |01-02-2016|    A   |12:30
9   |02-02-2016|    D   |07:00
12  |02-02-2016|    D   |08:30
10  |02-02-2016|    C   |07:30
11  |02-02-2016|    E   |08:00
13  |02-02-2016|    E   |09:00
14  |02-02-2016|    A   |09:30
```

Answer (score 3):

```
select t1.*
from XYZ t1
join (
  select Date, Product, min(Time) as minTime
  from XYZ 
  group by Date, Product
) t2 using(Date, Product)
order by str_to_date(t1.Date, '%d-%m-%Y'), t2.minTime, t1.Time
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/00209f/3

Comment: @Hogan I don't get your point. I get the min time for each product and date in the subquery. And then i'm sorting by minTime for each day.

Comment: @Hogan I'm unable to see the fiddle (I think the server is overloaded) but I created a table in my local DB. Pauls statement produces exactly the desired output. +1 for this.

Comment: Ok this is very subtle so it should explain more -- when you order by t2.minTime you are actually partitioning by Date and Product since the sub-query is grouped by those two fields.  Nice job.

Comment: @Hogan Ahh, now it works. Slooooowly. Probably they are throttling people without an "a" in their nicknames. ;-)

Comment: @PerlDog -- That makes sense 8)

Comment: @MakJ - It works because the data is already sorted by Date and Time and MySQL keeps that order. But as far as i know, there is no guarantee that this behaviour will never change. I recommend always to define the expected order explicitly... Here is an example how things can change: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7abf0/2). I didn't touch the data, just defined a primary key and an index. And the order changed.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly what u want to do is the following:

```
Select * from XYZ
order by date ,time
```

This will order the days, and then the time within each day.

Comment: This is not what the question asked for.

Comment: This won't work you need to have the product with the min time ordered for each day.